# ¿Como puedo Editar y Borrar en nuxt 3 con pinia?

Tags: vue3, nuxt, store, pinia

estoy intentando hacer un proyecto con nuxt 3 en el cual tengo un formulario para crear entradas de libros. Hasta aquí todo bien, pero a la hora de borrar una entrada o editarla no soy capaz de hacerlo, alguna sugerencia?
Mi store de pinia se ve así:

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import { uid } from "uid";

interface Libro{
    id: string;
    titulo: string;
    autor: string;
    genero: string;
    sinopsis: string;
    estado: string;
}
export const useLibroStore = defineStore('libro', {
    state: ()=>({
        libros: [] as Libro[]
    }),
    getters:{
        getLibroById: (state) =>(libroid:string)=> state.libros.find(libro => libro.id === libroid)       
    },
    actions: {
        addLibro(
            this:{libros: Libro[]},
            titulo:string,
            autor:string, 
            genero:string, 
            sinopsis:string,
            estado:string){
            const libroNuevo: Libro={
                id:uid(),
                titulo,
                autor,
                genero,
                sinopsis,
                estado,
            }
            this.libros.push(libroNuevo)
        },
        deleteLibro(id:string){
          this.libros.filter(libro => libro.id !== id)
          
        },
        updateLibro( id:string){
           
           this.libros= this.libros.find(libro => libro.id === id);
          
        }
        
    }
})
```

Para borrar en el botón que tengo incorporado uso : @click= "libroStore.deleteLibro" pero no me funciona.

y para editar la tarjeta necesito recuperar los datos pero no soy capaz, he creado una ruta dinámica que si funciona pero no se rellena el formulario.
Alguna ayuda por favor!! Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu accion borrar y tu accion editar no hacen nada... por eso no te funciona...